# Iterating over node names in \foreach gives \inaccessible error

Tags: tikz-pgf, foreach

I would like to connect my cylindric masses with a bold horizontal line like displayed in the following picture:

[image: shaft model mit masses J_i]

The following code works fine for the first connection:

```
\documentclass{standalone}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{shapes,intersections}

\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}

\tikzstyle{mass} = [draw, fill=gray!20, cylinder, shape aspect=1, minimum width=1.5cm, minimum height=1cm, shape border rotate=180];

\foreach \xpos/\name/\tag in {0/J1/J_1, 2/J2/J_2, 4/J3/J_3, 6/J4/\cdots, 8/J5/J_n}
    {
    \node[mass, name=\name] at (\xpos cm,0cm) {};
    \draw[shift=(\name.center)] node[] {$\tag$};
    }

\path[name path=line1] (J2.before top) -- (J2.after top);
\path[name path=line2] (J2.top) -- (J2.bottom);
\draw[name intersections={of=line1 and line2}, thick] (J1.east) -- (intersection-1);

\end{tikzpicture}
```

For the obvious reasons, I would like to make the connections using a `\foreach` loop. I tried the following:

```
\documentclass{standalone}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{shapes,intersections}

\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}

\tikzstyle{mass} = [draw, fill=gray!20, cylinder, shape aspect=1, minimum width=1.5cm, minimum height=1cm, shape border rotate=180];

\foreach \xpos/\name/\tag in {0/J1/J_1, 2/J2/J_2, 4/J3/J_3, 6/J4/\cdots, 8/J5/J_n}
    {
    \node[mass, name=\name] at (\xpos cm,0cm) {};
    \draw[shift=(\name.center)] node[] {$\tag$};
    }

\foreach \name1/\name2 in {J1/J2, J2/J3, J3/J4, J4/J5}
    {
    \path[name path=line1] (\name2.before top) -- (\name2.after top);
    \path[name path=line2] (\name2.top) -- (\name2.bottom);
    \draw[name intersections={of=line1 and line2}, thick] (\name1.east) -- (intersection-1); 
    }

\end{tikzpicture}
```

Unfortunately, in the second example, the second `\foreach` loop does not work. LaTeX throws an `\inaccessible` error during compilation. It seems that I cannot access the node names in the second `\foreach` loop in the way I did?

Comment: Use `\namea` and `\nameb`; control sequences cannot contain both numbers and letters(and just one number, actually).

Comment: Thanks, @egreg! That solved the problem.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can't use numbers together with letters in control sequences.

A control sequence name can be either a single nonletter or a sequence of one or more letters.

So `\name1` is an illegal name in this context and generally; in some situations it could seem to work, but don't count on this.

Use

```latex
\foreach \namea/\nameb in {J1/J2, J2/J3, J3/J4, J4/J5}
    {
    \path[name path=line1] (\nameb.before top) -- (\nameb.after top);
    \path[name path=line2] (\nameb.top) -- (\nameb.bottom);
    \draw[name intersections={of=line1 and line2}, thick] (\namea.east) -- (intersection-1); 
    }
```

Numbers in path or coordinate names are legal, but for completely different reasons.

Answer (score 4):

Since egreg corrected your code, I simplify it by using loops with a single variable since the other two can be generated by a single variable.

[image: screenshot]

```
\documentclass[border=5mm,tikz]{standalone}
\usetikzlibrary{shapes,intersections}

\begin{document}

\begin{tikzpicture}

\tikzset{mass/.style={draw, fill=gray!20, cylinder, shape aspect=1, minimum width=1.5cm, minimum height=1cm, shape border rotate=180}}

\foreach \tag[count=\xpos from 0] in {J_1,J_2,J_3,\cdots,J_n}
    {
    \node[mass, name=J\xpos] at (2*\xpos,0) {};
    \draw[shift=(J\xpos.center)] node[] {$\tag$};
    }

\foreach \n [evaluate=\n as \lastn using int(\n+1)] in {0,1,2,3}
    {
    \path[name path=line1] (J\lastn.before top) -- (J\lastn.after top);
    \path[name path=line2] (J\lastn.top) -- (J\lastn.bottom);
    \draw[name intersections={of=line1 and line2}, thick] (J\n.east) -- (intersection-1); 
    }

\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

Comment: Thanks for streamlining my code and sharing your improvements! I adapted my code accordingly.
Just out of curiosity, may I ask why you prefer `\tikzset` over `\tikzstyle` to define the style?